# Javascript not reading value on getElementById

Tags: javascript

Trying to propagate a value to five input fields on a button press. I am trying:

```
<input name="common<?php echo"$timeItem"?>" id="common<?php echo"$timeItem"?>" 
class="form-control input-sm" style="width:55px; height:20px; margin:0; padding:2px;  text-align: center;" type="text" value="111">
<button type="button"

onclick='
myElement = document.getElementById("common<?php echo $temp;?>").value;

document.getElementById("time_id<?php echo $temp;?>").innerHTML = myElement;

<?php $temp=$temp-1;?>

document.getElementById("time_id<?php echo $temp;?>").innerHTML = myElement;

<?php $temp=$temp-1;?>

document.getElementById("time_id<?php echo $temp;?>").innerHTML = myElement;

<?php $temp=$temp-1;?>

document.getElementById("time_id<?php echo $temp;?>").innerHTML = myElement;

<?php $temp=$temp-1;?>

document.getElementById("time_id<?php echo $temp;?>").innerHTML = myElement'>
```

Click me to update.

but I am being told "Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null".

I just cannot see why this is not picking up the value of the input text field which seems to have the right spelling!

**EDIT:** This is how it is rendered by the browser - easier to read:

```
<td><input name="time_id176" id="time_id_id176"  ...  type="text" value="0:00">
</td>
<td><input name="time_id177" id="time_id_id177"  ...  type="text" value="0:00">
</td>
<td><input name="time_id178" id="time_id_id178"  ...  type="text" value="0:00">
</td>
<td><input name="time_id179" id="time_id_id179"  ...  type="text" value="0:00">
</td>
<td><input name="time_id180" id="time_id_id180"  ...  type="text" value="0:00">
</td>

<td> 
<input name="common180" id="common180" class="form-control ... type="text" value="111">
<button type="button"

onclick='
myElement = document.getElementById("common180").value;

document.getElementById("time_id180").innerHTML = myElement;


document.getElementById("time_id179").innerHTML = myElement;


document.getElementById("time_id178").innerHTML = myElement;


document.getElementById("time_id177").innerHTML = myElement;


document.getElementById("time_id176").innerHTML = myElement'>
Click blah blah.</button>
</td>
```

Comment: You should check `$temp` and see whether in dom the element does exist. It seems the id is not used in page.

Comment: Sorry the $temp is set outside of this `<?php $temp=$timeItem; ?>`. It is all creating HTML/JS the way I wanted it to, just the myElement is NULL according to the Chrome debug tools.

Comment: GOT IT!!!! `id="time_id_id72"` in the input fields NOT `time_id72` - oops. Thanks for helping me find it!

Comment: innerHTML will not work on `input` elements as well. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input has an id of `time_id_id176`, while your js is `document.getElementById("time_id176")`. Should be `document.getElementById("time_id_id176")`.

Or maybe you should change the code for generating input tags, since `time_id_id176` doesn't make more sense than `time_id176`.

Secondly, `document.getElementById("time_id176").innerHTML = myElement;` will not work. Input is a self-closed tag, it has no innerHTML. Right way is set to its `value`:

```
document.getElementById("time_id176").value = myElement;
```

Comment: Looks like you won the first right answer award by a minute! Thanks for all the pointers.

Answer (score 0):

```
id="time_id_id176"
```

Is your id of your elements and then you are calling

```
getElementById("time_id176").innerHTML
```

so you need to fix your id scheme or you need to getelem by name

and thank you for your edit showing the generated html could not have answered with just the php in this case

Answer (score 0):

Which browser are you using? you should use `.value` instead of `.innerHTML` to set a value to `input` element.

oh, and ids of inputs are mismatching as well.

Comment: Yep thanks - very observant! I noticed the mismatch and found the solution `document.getElementById("time_id_id883").value = myElement;` about eight mins after you posted. Thanks for the solution. I got there in the end. I am a complete JS newb so a lot is by trial and (lots of) error. If I had seen your post I would have saved eight mins - but struggling away probably will make it stick a bit better!